# some problems with python code, what i do wrong?

Tags: python, openpyxl

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import openpyxl

# Create a list of city URLs that you want to scrape
city_urls = ['http://www.regionservis.cz/databaze-mest-a-obci/obec/3190-benesov',
             'http://www.regionservis.cz/databaze-mest-a-obci/obec/3191-braslovice',
             # Add more URLs here
            ]

# Iterate over the list of city URLs and scrape the data for each city
for url in city_urls:
    # Make a request to the website and get the HTML content
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.content
    # Parse the HTML content with Beautiful Soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    # Find the table elements in the HTML and extract the data you need
    tables = soup.find_all('table')
    data = {}
    for table in tables:
        rows = table.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            cols = row.find_all('td')
            # Extract the data from the columns and store it in the data dictionary

    # Find the first table and extract the data
    table = tables[0]
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        if len(cols) == 2:
            key = cols[0].text.strip()
            value = cols[1].text.strip()
            data[key] = value

    # Find the second table and extract the data
    table = tables[1]
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        if len(cols) == 2:
            key = cols[0].text.strip()
            value = cols[1].text.strip()
            data[key] = value

    # Find the third table and extract the data
    table = tables[2]
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        if len(cols) == 2:
            key = cols[0].text.strip()
            value = cols[1].text.strip()
            data[key] = value

    # Write the data to the Excel file
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('cities.xlsx')
    sheet = wb['Sheet1']
    row = sheet.max_row + 1
    sheet.cell(row=row, column=1).value = data['name']
    sheet.cell(row=row, column=2).value = data['Město']
    sheet.cell(row=row, column=3).value = data['Okres']
    # Add the data for the other columns
    wb.save('cities.xlsx')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PY\UW\czech\main.py", line 62, in <module>
    sheet.cell(row=row, column=1).value = data['name']
KeyError: 'name'
```

i need worked code in python

Comment: "i need worked code in python" – then you'll need to just figure out why your scraping code doesn't populate `name`.

Comment: `data` dictionary does not have a key called `name`. Hence the KeyError.

Comment: It also doesn't appear to have key 'Město' this is a value for the key 'Statut:', and while 'Okres' exists it has a colon at the end, 'Okres:' All the keys end in colons.   Therefore all of those lines will return the same key error. You might want to do a check first for the key in the dict like if **'name' in data** and only then execute the line **sheet.cell(row=row, column=1).value = data['name']** if True. And handle the colons.